# moving uploaded files not working

Tags: php

i have no idea why this isn't working, and the strange part is... it was working and now its not

upon userlogin i run this:

```
if($query_num_rows==0)
{
echo 'Invalid username/password combination.';
}
else if($query_num_rows==1)
{
echo 'ok';
if(!file_exists ('userdata/'.strtolower($username))){
    mkdir("userdata/".strtolower($username));
}
if(!file_exists ('userdata/'.strtolower($username).'/tracks')){
    mkdir("userdata/".strtolower($username)."/tracks");
}
if(!file_exists ('userdata/'.strtolower($username).'/artwork')){
    mkdir("userdata/".strtolower($username)."/artwork");
}
if(!file_exists ('userdata/'.strtolower($username).'/pdf')){
    mkdir("userdata/".strtolower($username)."/pdf");
}

if(!file_exists ('userdata/'.strtolower($username).'/episodes')){
    mkdir("userdata/".strtolower($username)."/episodes");
}
```

which makes a directory for that user

and for all my uploader's (uploading a profile image , photo, etc) i use these commands:

```
$currentdir = getcwd();

    if(isset($_FILES['avtar-file']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['avtar-file']['name'])){
        $target = $currentdir .'/userdata/'.$username.'/'. basename($_FILES['avtar-file']['name']);
        if($_FILES['avtar-file']['type']=="image/jpeg"||$_FILES['avtar-file']['type']=="image/jpg"||$_FILES['avtar-file']['type']=="image/png"){
            move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES['avtar-file']["tmp_name"] , $target );
            $avtarPath = 'dashboard/userdata/'.$username.'/'.basename($_FILES['avtar-file']['name']);
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['avtaroldfilename'])){
            $currentPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
            if(file_exists($currentPath.'/'.$_POST['avtaroldfilename'])){
                unlink($currentPath.'/'.$_POST['avtaroldfilename']);
            }
        }

    }
    else if(!empty($_POST['avtaroldfilename'])){
        $avtarPath = $_POST['avtaroldfilename'];
    }
```

The folders for the users are being generated with 755 privileges as all as /userdata has 755 privileges

as of now its like the uploader isn't working at all

Comment: @Dagon no errors, no warnings thats the part thats blowing my mind

Comment: at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: try to check target folder permission writable

Comment: @jothi its set to 775, still not working

Comment: @Dagon

i added that (although i already had some of that line)

and i also added if ( move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['avtar-file']["tmp_name"] , $target ) )
      echo "Download completed";
   else
      echo "Error";
  }

and its still not working, nor is it showing any of these echos

Comment: are you sure its even getting to the move function and not stopped by one of the if() checks

Comment: @jothi i tried that

Comment: Make sure your folder has read write permission

Comment: you have a file type checking line. As you said in one of your comment that 'nor is it showing any of these echos', then try to check the file type. Check the extension of the file. In my experience I found '.jpg' and '.JPG' are different. Check that part.